# Replace a keyword in Regular Expressions (PCRE)

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I've just started to learn Regex in PCRE and trying to write a regex for replacing keyword "men" with "women" in a string.
Basically the string is a text that contains "men" all over it (no case sensitive) and I want to replace it with "women"
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: this is most basic regex..what have you tried?

Comment: for something so simple `str_replace()` is recommended

Answer (score 0):

Consider this regex with explanation:

```
<?php
$string = "This is a man's world and it wouldn't be nothing without a woman or a girl.";
$regex = '~     # opening delimiter
            \b  # word boundary
            man # man literally
            \b  # word boundary
          ~x';  # closing delimiter

echo preg_replace($regex, "woman", $string);
# This is a woman's world and it wouldn't be nothing without a woman or a girl.
?>
```

As already mentionned in the comments, for your specific example simple string functions would possibly be more suitable.
To actually *learn*  regular expressions, `StackOverflow` might not be the most appropriate place, better go for **http://www.regular-expressions.info** or **http://www.regexone.com** for starters.